# Laravel Code coverage: how to test default BroadcastServiceProvider?

Tags: laravel, phpunit, code-coverage

Just for sake to full code coverage test, I'd like to test the file `/app/Providers/BroadcastServiceProvider.php` created automatically buy laravel installer.

Could you suggest me a simple test?

Comment: Exclude the file from coverage as it is generated code. Don't cover just for the sake of it, no a good advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a manual test

Create an basic event, and set the set the driver to  `'broadcast'`
Set `.env` to have the broadcast provider of your choice (Redis would be the optimal choice).
Broadcast a new instance of your event using the helper function `broadcast()`
And check you driver to see if the event was broadcasted.